# Problemas al cargar datos en una realación 1:N con hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en Java utilizando SpringBoot y Hibernate para trabajar con la base de datos. En este proyecto tengo una relación OneToMany la he definido de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Profesor extends Usuario {
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profesor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Sugerencia> sugerencias;
    
    
}

public class Sugerencia implements Serializable {
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "usuarios_correo")
    private Profesor profesor;
    
   
}
```

El problema esta en que cuando quiero recoger los objetos de la lista sugerencias esta me aparece en null y no veo donde puede estar el error[image: sugerencias null]

Aquí esta el código donde obtengo la lista de sugerencias:

```
 public void eliminarProfesores(Profesor profesor) {
        if (profesor.getSugerencias() != null || !profesor.getSugerencias().isEmpty()) {
            
            for (Sugerencia sugerencia : profesor.getSugerencias()) {
                
                sugerenciaService.eliminarSugerencia(sugerencia);
            }
        }
        this.profesorDAO.delete(profesor);
    }
```

Recibo el profesor y compruebo que la lista no sea null o este vacía. Si hay sugerencia las elimino y una vez que las elimino elimino el profesor.

Comment: Cambiale el `fetch` a EAGER y subí el código donde estás obteniendo la lista de sugerencias. ¿Es dentro de una transacción? ¿La lista es null o es una lista de proxys?

Comment: @GavilanPatagonico ya he subido el código donde estoy obteniendo la lista de sugerencias